# A single .htaccess for both localhost and server (not only redirects differ)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've got a really dumb PHP webhosting with Apache, which means I cannot edit the httpd.conf file to create VirtualHosts. All configuration needs to be done using .htaccess files.

I'd like to use a single .htaccess file for both the development (localhost) and live servers (but with differences for both environments).

There are many answers on how to do different redirects based on the HTTP_HOST and using RewriteCond. This is not useful for me.

I need to do several other things (not only redirects) in different ways on localhost. This is my example .htaccess from live server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    php_value session.save_path "/www/doc/...masked.../app/sessions"
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
    php_value session.cookie_lifetime 86400
    php_value session.gc_probability 1
    php_value session.gc_divisor 1

    php_value pcre.recursion_limit 1000000
    php_value pcre.backtrack_limit 1000000000

    RewriteRule ^13/phpinfo.php$ index.php [L]

    # front controller
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule !\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Please note the php_value calls. I do not know how to execute them only on the live server.** And I do not want to "replace" them with ini_set() PHP calls (it is prohibited by my hosting).

Is there a simple way to do this in a single file? The root of the problem is it is difficult to manage the two versions of the file, one of which cannot be stored locally (because of the same name of both files).

I can think of a workaround - setting different AccessName on localhost, e.g. to `.localaccess`. Then I could have both local and server versions in my development environment and update both of them. But having the rules in a single file would be much much better.

Thank you for any answers.